# Partial regression plots vs scatter plots for checking linearity

Tags: data-visualization, multiple-regression, assumptions

In a multiple linear regression analysis, what is the most suitable plot for checking linearity? I have seen a number of examples that use scatterplots as a preliminary test to use a linear model. But, aren't partial regression plots more reasonable?

Answer (score 2):

You don't say which scatterplots you've seen used for this -- that is, what's on the x and y axes?

However, my usual practice (and the output of R) agrees with [this page](https://people.duke.edu/%7Ernau/testing.htm#linearity) from Duke University on testing linearity:

> How to diagnose: nonlinearity is usually most evident in a plot of
> observed versus predicted values or a plot of residuals versus
> predicted values, which are a part of standard regression output. The
> points should be symmetrically distributed around a diagonal line in
> the former plot or around horizontal line in the latter plot, with a
> roughly constant variance.  (The residual-versus-predicted-plot is
> better than the observed-versus-predicted plot for this purpose,
> because it eliminates the visual distraction of a sloping pattern.)
> Look carefully for evidence of a "bowed" pattern, indicating that the
> model makes systematic errors whenever it is making unusually large or
> small predictions. In multiple regression models, nonlinearity or
> nonadditivity may also be revealed by systematic patterns in plots of
> the residuals versus individual independent variables.

Partial regression plots don't get mentioned and I'm not sure why you think they would be better.